# [turtle_pointer-6] process has died when running tf tutorial

Tags: ros, tf-tutorial, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to follow the tutorial from here :

```
http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf
```

But there's some error and a process died. This is the full message :

---

```
roslaunch turtle_tf turtle_tf_demo.launch 
... logging to /home/albert/.ros/log/52b0e6d8-1099-11e2-aceb-5404a6dc3a5e/roslaunch-Albert-PC-11357.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://Albert-PC:50707/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /scale_angular
 * /scale_linear
 * /turtle1_tf_broadcaster/turtle
 * /turtle2_tf_broadcaster/turtle

NODES
  /
    sim (turtlesim/turtlesim_node)
    teleop (turtlesim/turtle_teleop_key)
    turtle1_tf_broadcaster (turtle_tf/turtle_tf_broadcaster.py)
    turtle2_tf_broadcaster (turtle_tf/turtle_tf_broadcaster.py)
    turtle_pointer (turtle_tf/turtle_tf_listener.py)

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [11373]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 52b0e6d8-1099-11e2-aceb-5404a6dc3a5e
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [11386]
started core service [/rosout]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[sim-2]: started with pid [11398]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[teleop-3]: started with pid [11415]
Reading from keyboard
---------------------------
Use arrow keys to move the turtle.
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[turtle1_tf_broadcaster-4]: started with pid [11446]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[turtle2_tf_broadcaster-5]: started with pid [11447]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[turtle_pointer-6]: started with pid [11448]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry_tutorials/turtle_tf/nodes/turtle_tf_listener.py", line 57, in <module>
    (trans,rot) = listener.lookupTransform('/turtle2', '/turtle1', rospy.Time())
tf.ExtrapolationException: Lookup would require extrapolation at time 1349626149.653091908, but only time 1349626149.653103113 is in the buffer, when looking up transform from frame [/turtle1] to frame [/turtle2]
[WARN] [WallTime: 1349626149.680432] Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: connection from sender terminated before handshake header received. 0 bytes were received. Please check sender for additional details.
[turtle_pointer-6] process has died [pid 11448, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry_tutorials/turtle_tf/nodes/turtle_tf_listener.py __name:=turtle_pointer __log:=/home/albert/.ros/log/52b0e6d8-1099-11e2-aceb-5404a6dc3a5e/turtle_pointer-6.log].
log file: /home/albert/.ros/log/52b0e6d8-1099-11e2-aceb-5404a6dc3a5e/turtle_pointer-6*.log
```

---

How to solve this problem? Thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45251/%5Bturtle_pointer-6%5D-process-has-died-when-running-tf-tutorial/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2012-10-07

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's probably a configuration problem. In any case, in order to follow with the tutorial, you can spawn the process that dies by hand:

rosrun turtle_tf turtle_tf_listener

Despite the aparition of the bizzarre 3rd turtle in the corner, the working nodes still being 3 :).

---

Originally posted by [sbragagnolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3205/sbragagnolo/) with karma: 203 on 2012-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jeanbuntu](https://answers.ros.org/users/74097/jeanbuntu/) on 2021-05-12**:
Interestingly, I just got the bizzare corner turtle, this didn't spawn the 2nd needed follower turtle.

ERROR] [1620796305.295081927]: "turtle2" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.

This is the error that I seem to get.

**Comment by [Fanon](https://answers.ros.org/users/126002/fanon/) on 2023-03-18**:
yep, that is what I am getting to this day-stationary corner turtle, but not the needed follower turtle

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue which I solved by running "rosmake turtle_tf rviz".

Ps. I skipped this command when going through the tutorial because I thought it was already installed and configured as the "rosdep install turtle_tf rviz" command returns the following message "#All required rosdeps installed successfully".

---

Originally posted by [Rodrigo Serviuc Pavezi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4406/rodrigo-serviuc-pavezi/) with karma: 21 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried everything only adding Exceptions works for me.
Here is the original post.
http://answers.ros.org/question/30784/tf-tutorial-warning-message/

---

Originally posted by [bombilee](https://answers.ros.org/users/4584/bombilee/) with karma: 86 on 2013-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1